# Custom x-axis and text with chart not displaying

Tags: image-charts

Being a 1-to-1 replacement, why does this code generate such a different bar chart? Going through the image-charts docs, this looks like it should work. I'm having problems getting the text to display next to the chart, as well as displaying the custom x-axis.

[image: What it should look like]

Original googleapis code

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=bhs&chs=250x70&chd=t:19&chco=39e600&chf=bg,s,f3f1e9&chxt=x,x&chm=N**%%20Low,000000,0,-1,18&chxl=1:|Low|Medium|High&chxp=0,0,25,42,100|1,13,34,71&chxs=0N**%,000000
```

Swapping out to image-charts

```
https://image-charts.com/chart?cht=bhs&chs=250x70&chd=t:19&chco=39e600&chf=bg,s,f3f1e9&chxt=x,x&chm=N**%%20Low,000000,0,-1,18&chxl=1:|Low|Medium|High&chxp=0,0,25,42,100|1,13,34,71&chxs=0N**%,000000
```

What's going on here? Tried breaking it down to the smallest possible pieces, but never had any success getting the x-axis or text within the chart to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Multiple x-axis](https://documentation.image-charts.com/reference/chart-axis/#visible-axes) (`chxt=x,x`) and [custom text marker](https://documentation.image-charts.com/reference/markers/#text-and-data-value-markers-chm) (`chm=N**%%20Low,000000,0,-1,18`) are supported in [Image Charts API](https://www.image-charts.com).

Here is the same chart in Image-Charts:

[image]

Now some little improvements:

- set an explicit axis range for the first x axis with `chxr=0,0,100` (axis=0, from 0 to 100)
- a bigger chart with `chs=350x90`
- make it chart retina display compliant with Image Charts own API (`icretina=1`)

[image]

*Disclaimer: I'm Image-Charts founder.*